# Maven Dependency Issues with library hierarchies

Tags: java, maven

I've typing myself in knots getting Maven to handle the dependencies between modules in my applications, and I'm wondering what's the best-practice way forwards.

I've got a set of libraries that I use for all of my application that look something like:

```
<shared-code>
  |---- common-lib
  |---- REST-lib
  |---- WebApp-lib
  |---- REST-Pom
  \---- WebApp-Pom
```

In reality there are more artefacts, but the important things are:

- common-lib when I store all my general purpose code
- REST-lib and WebApp-lib are more specialist libraries that depend on common-lib
- REST-Pom and WebApp-Pom are parent POMs for different types of application and, critically, they have a dependency on either REST-lib or WebApp-lib
- All 5 of the artefacts in  are released together and always have the same version.

When I come to write my application I've got:

```
<application-code>
  |---- parent-pom
  |---- module-1
  |---- module-2
  \---- module-3
```

- parent-pom extends either REST-Pom or WebApp-Pom and adds project specific information (e.g. SCM information)
- module-1, module-2, module-3 all extend parent-pom
- As with the , all of the artefacts in the  are released together with a common version, but (critically) NOT the same one as the .

Following the advice from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979198/maven-how-to-read-the-parent-pom-version), I've been defining dependencies in the form:

```
<dependency>
    <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I like this because I don't have to go through each POM when I make a release setting all of version.

The trouble is that `${project.parent.version}` is evaluated separately for each POM and doesn't always evaluate to the same thing.

- parent-pom evaluates ${project.parent.version} to the version of either REST-Pom or WebApp-Pom, which is in lock step with common-lib, so we've got the correct value.
- module-1, module-2 and module-3 evaluates ${project.parent.version} to the version of parent-pom, which is different.

What I (think) I need is an expression I can use as the version which says "the version of this project, and not the thing that extends it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent poms are **also** designed to hold dependencies included ( `<dependencies>` ) or included on-demand (`<dependencyManagement>`) by their children.
Define them in the `dependencyManagement` element of the parent pom :

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
     </dependency>
      <!-- and so for -->
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And let child projects refer them in their own pom :

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  </dependency>
  <!-- and so for -->
</dependencies>
```

You can notice that the dependency version doesn't need and **should not be** set by the child as it was defined by the parent pom.